# Riesz's Lemma for finite-dimensional spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $Z$ be any linear normed space and $Y$ a closed subspace of $Z$, then by Riesz's Lemma there exist an element $z_\theta \in Z$ such that $||z_\theta||=1$ and  $dist(z_\theta,Y)<\theta$ where $\theta\in (0,1)$, i.e we can get away from the closed subspace arbitrarily close to $1$ and still be on the unit ball.

When however, $Z$ is a **finite** dimensional linear normed space, one can find an element $z\in Z$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(z,Y)=1$ with $\|z\|=1$. Could someone give me an idea of ​​what happens in finite dimensional case?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you are asking about.  Perhaps about applying this [Riesz Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) in finite dimensional normed linear spaces?

Comment: In the case where $Y$ is a finite dimensional subspace of the normed space $X$, one can find $x\in S(X)$ with $\text{dist}\,(x,Y)=1$. This can be found in Lemma 1.4.22 of Robert Megginson's *An Introduction to Banach Space Theory*.

Comment: I find this a legitimate question, once the wording is improved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the following result doesn't seem to be well-known, I'll post its statement and an outline of its proof, both  taken from the Lemma mentioned in the link in my comment above:

Theorem:

Let $Y$ be a finite dimensional subspace of the normed vector space $X$. Then there is an element $x\in X$ of norm one with $\text{dist}\,(x,Y)=1$.

Outline of proof:

Let $z\in X\setminus Y$. Then, as $Y$ is closed,  $t=\text{dist}\,(z, Y)\ne0$. One can show, using the fact that $t^{-1}Y=Y$,  that
$$\text{dist}\,(t^{-1}z,Y)=1.$$ Let $(y_n)$ be a sequence in $Y$ with 
$$\Vert y_n-t^{-1}z\Vert\rightarrow 1\tag1$$ Then $(y_n)$ is bounded and as $Y$ is finite dimensional, there is  a subsequence $(y_{n_k})$ of $(y_n)$ that converges to some $y\in Y$.

Let $x=y-t^{-1}z$.

One can use $(1)$ to show that $\Vert x\Vert =1$.

Using the fact that $y-Y=Y$, one can show that $\text{dist}\,(x, Y)=1$.

Thus, $x$ is as advertised.

Comment: Why $t^{-1} Y = Y$?

Comment: $Y$ is a subspace; so, $t^{-1}Y=\{ t^{-1} y\mid y\in Y\}$ is just $Y$ again.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: why does *"$(y_n)$ is bounded and as $Y$ is finite dimensional"* implies *"there is a subsequence $(y_{n_k})$ of $(y_n)$ that converges to some $y∈Y$"*?

Comment: @JohnMars Finite dimensional spaces have compact unit balls.

Comment: @DavidMitra,  know this post is several years old already, but just wondering how you know there is a sequence yn in Y that gets to distance 1 within $t^(-1)z$ Is it possible that $t^(-1)z$ is so far away from Y that no element of Y is within 1 distance away?

Comment: @William The distance of $t^{-1}z$ to $Y$ is 1; so it follows from the definition, no?

Answer (score 5):

This is a comment to David Mitra's answer. There is a beautiful result by Krein, Milman and Krasnoselski based on the [Borsuk–Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) which strengthens the Riesz lemma in finite dimensions.

> **Theorem**. Let $M$ and $N$ be finite-dimensional subspaces of a normed space. If $\dim M > \dim N$, then there is $x_0\in M$ such that ${\rm dist}(x_0, N)=\|x_0\|$.

I am happy to provide a proof on request. I am very curious whether there exists a proof of this statement which would avoid using the Borsuk–Ulam theorem.

Reference:

1. M. Kreĭn, M. Krasnoselski, D. Milman, On defect numbers of operators on Banach spaces and related geometric problems, *Trudy Inst. Mat. Akad. Nauk Ukrain. SSR*, **11** (1948), 97–112.