# Infinite dimensional Banach spaces and sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. 
$a)$ Prove that there is a sequence $x=(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ in $X$ such that $||x_n||=1$ for all $n$ satisfying 
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{dist}(x_{n+1},\mathrm{Span} \{x_1,...,x_n \})\geq 1, n\geq 1
\end{equation*}
$b)$ Based on $a)$, show that the closed unit ball in $X$ cannot be compact. 
 
My attempt:

 I want to prove it by induction: if $n=0$, then I can take any $0 \neq x \in X$ and normalize it. Thus $\mathrm{dist}(x,\mathrm{Span} \{ 0 \})= ||x||=1$ and the inequality is true. Suppose now it's true for $n-1$. Then for $x_1,...,x_n$ I can choose $x_{n+1} \notin \mathrm{Span}\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ (since $X$ is infinite dimensional) such that $||x_{n+1}||=1$. Thus $\mathrm{dist}(x_{n+1},\mathrm{Span} \{x_1,...,x_n \})=\mathrm{inf}_{x \in \mathrm{Span}\{x_1,...,x_n\} }d(x_{n+1},x) \geq 1$ since $d(x_{n+1},x)=d(x,x_{n+1}) \geq \mathrm{dist}(x, <x_{n+1}>) \geq 1$ ($<x_{n+1}>$ is $1$ dimensional and I can apply the induction hypothesis). In particular I get that $||x_n-x_m|| \geq 1$ for $n \neq m$  
For part $b)$ suppose the closed unit ball is compact, i.e. every sequence in it has a convergent subsequence. But this is not true for my sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq1}$ since $||x_n-x_m|| \geq 1$ for $n \neq m$. Am I right?

Comment: Your argument for $(a)$ is flawed.  In fact it implies that you can choose $x_{n+1}$ to be any unitary element that is not in $\operatorname{span}\left\{x_1,\dots,x_n\right\}$, which is clearly false. Take for instance $n=1$, $x_1=(1,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $x_2=(\sqrt{1-\varepsilon^2},\varepsilon)$ for small $\varepsilon$. Then $x_2$ satisfies your conditions but clearly $d(x_2,\left\langle x_1\right\rangle)\ll 1$.

Comment: One usually uses [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) to prove a) with \begin{equation*}
\mathrm{dist}(x_{n+1},\mathrm{Span} \{x_1,...,x_n \})\geq \alpha, n\geq 1
\end{equation*} for any (fixed) $0<\alpha<1$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163500/an-application-of-riesz-lemma).  Riesz's lemma has a slight refinment though, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313664/rieszs-lemma-for-finite-dimensional-spaces). I think you might get your result using this result.